# Python Generator memory benefits for large readins?

Tags: python, generator

I'm wondering about the memory benefits of python generators in this use case (if any). I wish to read in a large text file that must be shared between all objects. Because it only needs to be used once and the program finishes once the list is exhausted I was planning on using generators.

The "saved state" of a generator I believe lets it keep track of what is the next value to be passed to whatever object is calling it. I've read that generators also save memory usage by not returning all the values at once, but rather calculating them on the fly. I'm a little confused if I'd get any benefit in this use case though.

Example Code:

```
def bufferedFetch():
    while True:
        buffer = open("bigfile.txt","r").read().split('\n')
        for i in buffer:    
            yield i
```

Considering that the buffer is going to be reading in the entire "bigfile.txt" anyway, wouldn't this be stored within the generator, for no memory benefit? Is there a better way to return the next value of a list that can be shared between all objects?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case no. You are reading the entire file into memory by doing `.read()`.

What you ideally want to do instead is:

```
def bufferedFetch():
    with open("bigfile.txt","r") as f:
        for line in f:
            yield line
```

The python `file` object takes care of line endings for you (*system dependent*) and it's built-in iterator will yield lines by simply iterating over it one line at a time (*not reading the entire file into memory*).